# Save xml file by path from user select

Tags: c#, xml, savefiledialog

I'm success to save objects in xml file by path that I given. 
now I want to save in path that user select( I want FileDialog Box that the user select in the computer exactly where to save and can to creat/replace new file.xml)

I try to do by this guide but I don't understand clearly so it doesn't works. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx

I will be more that happy to get some help. Thanks and have a good day. :)

Comment: Please show us what code you have so far, and we might be able to help you get it working.

Comment: define "it doesn't work"

Comment: I deleted it because i have no successed to copy it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OpenFileDialog like this:

```
OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
theDialog.Title = "Open Text File";
theDialog.Filter = "TXT files|*.txt";
theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // if user selected a file, show it's name
    MessageBox.Show(theDialog.FileName.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I look for. Thanks. There is any way to save on something without delete it ? I mean if I have text file I want to open it and save on the continue the text not instead the text ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you are asking. Do you want to select a existing file?